# Return 0 in sum when no values to sum - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

Trying to return 0 if any of these columns have no values returned, in my particular case 'Past Due' has no values to total, so it is returned, so i get the return in the second snippet here.  How can I return something if these are no values to count?

```
SELECT ClientDeliveryStatus,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ClientDeliveryStatus = 'Past Due' THEN 1 
        WHEN ClientDeliveryStatus = 'Due Tomorrow' THEN 1 
        WHEN ClientDeliveryStatus = 'Due Today' THEN 1 
        WHEN ClientDeliveryStatus = 'Due Beyond' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ClientDeliveryStatus
```

Current Result:

```
    ClientDeliveryStatus    Total
    Due Beyond              1
    Due Today               3
    Due Tomorrow            51
```

Desired Result:

```
    ClientDeliveryStatus    Total
    Due Beyond              1
    Due Today               3
    Due Tomorrow            51
    Past Due                0
```

Example data:

TABLE1:

```
ClientDeliveryStatus
Due Tomorrow
Due Tomorrow
Due Tomorrow
Due Beyond  
Due Beyond  
Due Tomorrow
Due Beyond
Due Beyond
Due Beyond
Due Today
Due Today

CREATE TABLE1 Table1 (ClientDeliveryStatus VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO Table1 Values ('Due Tomorrow'), ('Due Tomorrow'), ('Due Tomorrow'), ('Due Beyond'), ('Due Beyond'), ('Due Beyond'), ('Due Beyond'), ('Due Today'),('Due Today')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a table of all the statuses.  If you don't already have a table, you can do this in the query itself:

```
SELECT ClientDeliveryStatus, COUNT(t.ClientDeliveryStatus) AS Total
FROM (SELECT 'Past Due' as cds UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Due Tomorrow' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Due Today' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Due Beyond'
     ) s LEFT JOIN
     Table t
     ON s.cds = t.ClientDeliveryStatus
GROUP BY s.cds;
```

Your original query is incorrect because it is missing a `GROUP BY` and overly complicated because of the `CASE` in the `SUM()`.

Comment: group by added, its there in the actual query, so not the problem. Would a union be simpler or do those perform slower?  Performance is a factor here, as always i guess, but more so than an average query for me.

Comment: @wondergoat77 . . . I wouldn't be surprised if you have a reference table with the values.  That would be the best approach.  `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`.

Comment: I actually dont, which is why retracted it.  Then it would be up to creating a temp table to accomplish what you did in less code.  Or do you think thats a better idea? Might be more readable but not sure about performance.  Will research if you dont care to answer that.

Comment: ended up being easier to just create a table of statuses, thanks for the help! If you would like to post that as an alternate soltution I can mark this as the solution.

Comment: @wondergoat77 . . . Using an existing table is the best solution, if you have one available.